# Both balls are red. What is the probability that they both came from the same box?

Tags: probability

I have a problem with a following task:

There are 3 red and 5 black balls in one box and 6 red and 4 white balls in
another.
 You pick box randomly and then pick a ball from it also randomly.
If both balls are red, what is the probability that they both came from the same box?

I figured out something like this, but unfortunetly answer is different and i don't know why.

Ok let's calculate it:
1)  Probability that first ball is from first box is :
$$\frac{\frac{3}{8}}{\frac{3}{8}+\frac{6}{10}} = \frac{5}{13}$$
2)Probability that second ball is from first box is :
$$\frac{\frac{2}{7}}{\frac{2}{7}+\frac{6}{10}} = \frac{10}{31}$$
3)Probability that first ball is from second box is :
$$\frac{\frac{6}{10}}{\frac{3}{8}+\frac{6}{10}} = \frac{8}{13}$$
4)Probability that first ball is from first box is :
$$\frac{\frac{5}{9}}{\frac{3}{8}+\frac{5}{9}} = \frac{40}{67}$$
So in my opinion it should look like these:
$$\frac{5}{13}*\frac{10}{31}+\frac{8}{13}*\frac{40}{67}= ... $$
It gives a specific number but it is not equal to answer in book which is
$$\frac{185}{374}$$
Can you help me, and explain where i did a mistake?

Comment: The probability experiment isn't clearly defined. What takes us from the setup of two boxes that you described to the observation of the colors of the two balls? Are we assuming that one of the two boxes is chosen randomly with equal probabilities for each, and then a ball is drawn from that chosen box, and then this process is repeated without replacement?

Comment: I have some additional information.
"You pick box randomly and then pick a ball from it also randomly."
That's all i know. I think that we can assume that process is repeated without replacement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would solve it as follows:

$$P(\text{Both from same box}\mid\text{Both red}) = \frac{P(\text{Two red from first box}) + P(\text{Two red from second box})}{P(\text{Two red})}$$

Now $P(\text{Two red from first box}) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{3}{8} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{2}{7}$

$P(\text{Two red from second box}) = \frac{1}{2}  \cdot \frac{6}{10} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{5}{9}$

$P(\text{One red from each box}) = 2\left(\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{3}{8} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{6}{10}\right)$

Then we can factor $1/4$ out of everything and get:

$$P = \frac{\frac{3}{8} \cdot \frac{2}{7} + \frac{6}{10} \cdot \frac{5}{9}}{\frac{3}{8} \cdot \frac{2}{7} + \frac{6}{10} \cdot \frac{5}{9} + 2 \cdot \frac{3}{8} \cdot \frac{6}{10}}$$